# Is there any way to "bridge" 2 different ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) implementations?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, esb, rhino-esb

Let's say I have 2 application domains. Domain A is using NServiceBus. Domain B is using RhinoESB. Is there any way to connect the 2, so that i can send messages from Domain A to Domain B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write custom service that will do the bridging, so yes. I am not aware or any existing services that you could use.